# Yielding a value from a coroutine in Python, a.k.a. convert callback to generator

Tags: python, asynchronous, functional-programming, generator, tornado

I'm new to Python and functional programming.  I'm using version 2.7.6

I'm using the Tornado framework to make async network requests.  From what I learned about functional programming, I want my data to stream through my code by using generators.  I have done most of what I need using generators and transforming the data as they stream through my function calls.

At the very end of my stream, I want to make a REST request for some data.  I have one for-loop just before I submit my data to Tornado, to initiate the pull, and then send the http request.  The http object provided by Tornado takes a callback function as an option, and always returns a Future--which is actually a Tornado Future object, and not the official Python Future.

My problem is that since I'm now using generators to pull my data through my code, I no longer want to use the callback function.  My reasoning for this is that after I get my data back from the callback, my data is now being pushed through my code, and I can no longer make use of generators.

My goal is to create an interface that appears like so:

```
urls = (...generated urls...)
responses = fetch(urls)
```

Where responses is a generator over the completed urls.

What I attempted to do--among many things--is convert the results from the callback into a generator. I was thinking about something like this, although I'm far from implementing it for other issues I will soon explain.  However, I wanted my fetch function to look something like this:

```
def fetch(urls):
    def url_generator():
        while True:
            val = yield
            yield val

    @curry
    def handler(gen, response):
        gen.send(response)

    gen = url_generator()

    for u in urls:
        http.fetch(u, callback=handler(gen))

    return gen
```

I simplified the code and syntax to focus on the problem, but I figured this was going to work fine.  My strategy was to define a coroutine/generator which I will then send the responses to, as I receive them.

What I'm having the most trouble with is the coroutine/generator.  Even if I define a generator in the above manner and perform the following, then I get an infinite loop--this is one of my main problems.

```
def gen():
    while True:
        val = yield
        print 'val', val
        yield val
        print 'after', val
        break

g = gen()
g.send(None)
g.send(10)

for e in g:
    print e
```

This prints `val 10 after 10` in the coroutine as expected with the break, but the for-loop never gets the value of 10.  It doesn't print anything while the break is there.  If I remove the break, then I get the infinite loop:

```
val None
None
after None
None
val None
None
after None
None
...
```

If I remove the for-loop, then the coroutine will only print `val 10` as it waits on the second yield.  I expect this.  However, using it doesn't produce anything.

Similarly, if I remove the for-loop and replace it with `print next(g)`, then I get a StopIteration error, which I assume means I called next on a generator that had no more values.

Anywho, I am at a complete loss while I plunge into more depth on Python.  I figure this is such a common situation in Python that somebody knows a great approach.  I searched for 'convert callback into generator' and such, but didn't have much luck.

On another note, I could possibly yield each future from the http request, but I didn't have much luck "waiting" on the yield for the future to complete.  I read a lot about 'yield from', but it seems to be Python 3 specific and Tornado doesn't seem to work on Python 3 yet.

Thanks for viewing, and thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Awesome question :). Well-written and researched.

Comment: Thanks.  This is my first question :)

Comment: Tornado does work with python 3, Is `@curry` your generator?

Comment: Thanks for popping in.  I had some issues with Tornado on py3, but I'll check it out again.  @curry comes from the PyMonad package.

Comment: When I was working with async generator, I had to pre-define the schema for the particular function. May be you should have a look at this http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html. I have just started working on PyMonad, I ll update you if i get a solution

Comment: Great suggestion. Checking it out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tornado works great on Python 3.

The problem with your simplified code above is that this isn't doing what you expect:

```
val = yield
```

You expect the generator to pause there (blocking your for-loop) until some other function calls `g.send(value)`, but that's not what happens. Instead, the code behaves like:

```
val = yield None
```

So the for-loop receives `None` values as fast as it can process them. After it receives each `None`, it implicitly calls `g.next()`, which is the same as `g.send(None)`. So, your code is equivalent to this:

```
def gen():
    while True:
        val = yield None
        print 'val', val
        yield val
        print 'after', val

g = gen()
g.send(None)
g.send(10)

while True:
    try:
        e = g.send(None)
        print e
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Reading this version of the code, where the implicit behaviors are made explicit, I hope it's clear why it's just generating `None` in an infinite loop.

What you need is some way for one function to add items to the head of a queue, while another function blocks waiting for items, and pulls them off the tail of the queue when they're ready. Starting in Tornado 4.2 we have exactly that:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html

The web spider example is close to what you want to do, I'm sure you can adapt it:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/queues.html

Comment: Jesse, thank you so much for this explanation.  I will mark it as correct once I get the proper behavior working and update my question with a working solution.  It's funny, after I perform this call I planned to put my results into MongoDB... and I was planning on using Motor!  I actually came across your personal site yesterday while researching it.  Small world :) Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help a bit. Let me know if there's anything else you need.