# Yielding inside coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have the following code.

```py
def gen():
    while True:        # line 2
        d = yield      # line 3
        yield d        # line 4

x = gen()
next(x)

for i in (3, 4, 5):
    print(x.send(i))   # line 10
```

When I run this, I get:

```
3
None
5
```

rather than:

```
3
4
5
```

which is what I would expect. I've already gone through several similar questions (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869593/yielding-a-value-from-a-coroutine-in-python-a-k-a-convert-callback-to-generato)) but I still don't understand what is happening here.

My understanding is as follows:
We prime the generator by calling `next(x)`, it starts execution and enters the `while` loop on line 2. On line 3, we have a `yield` statement and execution pauses. On line 10, we send the value `3`. Execution resumes on line 3, `d` is set to `3`, and we yield back `d`. On line 10, `send` returns the yielded value (`3`). The generator continues execution until we are back to the `yield` statement on line 3, etc.

Is this incorrect? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you use two `yield`s?

Comment: @KellyBundy one to receive a value from `send`, one to return a value

Comment: But *both* return a value...

Comment: @KellyBundy do you mind elaborating? I am relatively new to this but I thought `d = yield` essentially serves to accept incoming data (blocking until there is data available) while `yield d` serves to produce outgoing data

Comment: @mlz7 `d = yield d` is legal syntax. You can do both at once.

Comment: @Axe319 Ah I see, so `d = yield` will always implicitly `yield None`?

Comment: It is more than "can do both at once" - you _always_ do both at once, but e.g. `yield d` does not save what it received and `d = yield` yields `None` while receiving a value.

Comment: Yes. Add something like `d = yield` before your `while` loop. `next(x)` will advance to that `yield` implicitly yielding `None`. `x.send(i)` will send in `i`, assigning it to `d` and advance to the next `yield`, yielding `d` back. And then repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = yield y` does two things:

1. Return `y`.
2. Assign the next sent value to `x`.

Without `y`, `None` gets returned. Without `x =`, the sent value just gets thrown away.

So what happens here is:

```
code         effects         comments
---------------------------------------------
d = yield    return None     ok, you ignore it
             d = 3
yield d      return 3        gets printed
             Throw away 4
d = yield    return None     gets printed
             d = 5
yield d      return 5        gets printed
```

You can fix it like this, always storing and returning every sent value:

```
def gen():
    d = None  # or `d = yield`, either works, just differently
    while True:
        d = yield d
```